# pulling multiple records from mongo using flask and python

Tags: python, mongodb, flask, cursor

I am still learning here and am currently trying to use FLASK to create to Restful interface

What I want to do is to pull out a collection of records from a mongo database.
I have find_one() working fine and am now exploring how to itterate over a cursor

This code only displays a single record when I know there are at least 5

```
@app.route('/oer/api/v1.0/getType/', methods = ['GET'])
def getType():

    # Prepare a dictionary object to hold the result of any processing
    result = {}

    # Get hold of DB connection
    db_connection = getDbConnection()
    db = db_connection['OER']
    # Extract all records passed for the paramater that matches "Type": ie MOOC
    oerType = request.args.get("oerType");
    # test to see that there is something in the string if so try to get a record
    # Not doing this test yet lets get it working with a known record first 

    for d in db.oer_records.find({"Type":oerType}): 
        result.update(make_public_page(d))

    return jsonify(result)
```

So it works but only returns a single json document not a collection?  I thought the result.update would append a new record each time through
FYI make_public_page() removes BISON ID's to allow jsonify to work.

This is what it returns

```
{
    "Account No": 1,
    "Country/ continent": "Argentina",
    "Educational Level": "Schools",
    "Educational Level (ISCED)": "2|3",
    "End year": "",
    "Funders": "",
    "Geolocation": "",
    "Initiative HQ address": "",
    "Initiative HQ city": "",
    "Initiative URL": "http://www.gleducar.org.ar",
    "Type": "OER"
}
```

Any help appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using `dict.update(dict2)` you are adding dictionary dict2's key-values pairs in to dict which result in one big dict. What you might want to do is creating a list of dicts instead.

```
mylist = []
mylist.append(dict)
```

Translated to your code:

```
@app.route('/oer/api/v1.0/getType/', methods = ['GET'])
def getType():

    # Prepare a dictionary object to hold the result of any processing
    result = []  # create a list instead of dict

    # Get hold of DB connection
    db_connection = getDbConnection()
    db = db_connection['OER']
    # Extract all records passed for the paramater that matches "Type": ie MOOC
    oerType = request.args.get("oerType");
    # test to see that there is something in the string if so try to get a record
    # Not doing this test yet lets get it working with a known record first 

    for d in db.oer_records.find({"Type":oerType}): 
        result.append(make_public_page(d))  # append to the list of dicts

    return jsonify(items=result)
```

Comment: Still very new to both python and flask do you mean add mylist = [] under the result ={}  then mylist.append(make_public_page(d))  ?

Comment: I am getting ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 36; 2 is required ? Thank you for your input !

Comment: @Richard change the last line to `return jsonify(items=result)`. I forgot that jsonify cannot return arrays. `make_public_page(d)` returns a dict, right?

Comment: That did the trick thank you - now got to sort out a response for null seraches and how to split them into batches of 10 records but getting then to print as a set makes a big difference !